# Newbie: linux command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, ubuntu-10.04

Two questions to ask:

**1.** I am using **scp** command to copy a file from a remote server, I am wondering how can I specify the place where to paste the copied file on my local computer?

for example, if I wanna copy a *test.txt* file from a remote server and paste it on my local computer under /home/myname/tmp/ what is the proper command?
is it

```
scp SERVER_ADDRESS /home/myname/tmp/
```

**2.** If I want to search a file whose name contain text of "test" , what is the command I should use? I mean search for any file with name *test* , ('_' is a wildcard)

**--------------------------- update  ------------------------**

what is the difference between "find" and "grep"?

Comment: Doesn't belong here - superuser.com, unix.stackexchange.com or maybe askubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1:

```
scp SERVER_ADDRESS:/path/to/remote/file.txt /path/to/local/file.txt
```

2:

```
find . -name "*test*"
```

This will search for files/directories containing "test" anywhere in the filename. The search will start from the current directory `.` To search in another path, use `find /path/ -name "*test*"`. If you only want to search in files, that is, exclude directories, then add `-type f` before the `-name` option.

Comment: What is the difference between find and grep?

Comment: `grep` searches the contents of files, not their names.

Comment: grep find text INSIDE files, and find finds file names.

Comment: Note that `-name` is case sensitive, use `-iname '*test*'` if you want to match regardless of case.

Answer (score 1):

First `man scp` is your friend (as are all man pages in general).

1. Yes: in full, that'd be like `scp server:/path/to/file.txt /local/path/`.
2. Your main options here are:

   `locate test` (if you have `locate` installed and its database is up to date)

   -or-

   `find /path/name -name '*test*'` to find any named files inside the /path/name directory and all its children.